# unable to drag jquery

Tags: jquery, drag

I am using this function for drag and drop. Calling this function onmousedown event. It does not work when I do mouse down for the first time but it works perfectly fine from the second mouse down event.

How can I make it work for the first time?

```
 function  DivMouseDown(id)
{
 alert("id:" +id);
//alert(" i m in DivMouseDown");
try
{

 jQuery('#'+ id).draggable({
   opacity:  0.5,
   revert: 'invalid',
    drag:function(ev,ui)
    {
    //alert("i m draggable");
    }
 });
}

catch (e)
{

 alert ("exception in DIVmouse down: "+ e);
}
```

Comment: where are you adding the mousedown event? is it added after you call 'draggable'?

Answer (score 1):

You should call that init function once the DOM is ready.

```
function initDivMouseDown(id)
{ 
    try {
        jQuery('#'+ id).draggable({ 
            opacity: 0.5, 
            revert: 'invalid', 
            drag:function(ev,ui) {
                // ADDED DIV ID HERE 
                alert($(this).attr('id') + " is being dragged");
            } 
        }); 
    } catch (e) {
        alert ("exception in DIVmouse down: "+ e); 
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    initDivMouseDown("my_div");
});
```